# EF6 using IContextFactory for repository classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, .net-4.8

I'm trying to add DI to my repository classes in order to maintain UoW and leaving my contexts short-lived, but still being able to test them via a specific mock context.
The best way I found for this is adding an `IContextFactory` interface that my repository class constructors take as parameter. So something like

```
public interface IContextFactory
{
    DbContext Create();
}


public class SQLiteContextFactory : IContextFactory
{
    public DbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyContext();
    }
}
```

and then changing my `UserRepository` as follows

```
public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly IContextFactory _contextFactory;
    public UserRepository(IContextFactory contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public User Read(int userId)
    {
        using (var context = _contextFactory.Create())
        {
            var user = context.Users
                .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == userId)
            return user;
        }
    }
```

However, since `context` now is of type `DbContext` instead of `MyContext`, it doesn't know about `Users`.

How would I solve this problem and still be able to test my repository functions?